# Is there a standard way to represent TSQL Minimum date in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, t-sql, datetime, minimum

I want to initialize a DateTime entity to the minimum possible date in TSQL.
(as you all know its `1/1/1753`)

Is there a standard way to represent this date in ASP.NET ?
I mean doing something like `DateTime.SQLMinValue` (this doesn't exist), instead of doing
`new DateTime(year, month, date)` ?

If so, please post it, Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime.MinValue;
```

...and the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqldatetime.minvalue.aspx) for reference.

Comment: If I have to compare it with some DateTime value, is it fine if I do DateTime.Now != (DateTime) SqlDateTime.MinValue or is there a better way to do that? Thanks for the answer :)

Comment: I can't remember if you can directly cast from SqlDateTime to DateTime. If not, then you could do DateTime.Now != new DateTime.Parse(SqlDateTime.MinValue.ToString());

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** Luke is right, extension methods are not an appropriate solution to this problem.

Comment: The fact that you can only call extensions on instances of a type rather than the type itself could lead to some *very* unintuitive code: `var confusing = new DateTime(2009, 12, 07).SQLMinValue();` etc.

Comment: Very good point Luke.  This is not the appropriate use of extension methods. Thanks for pointing this out.